# discrete math use an element argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Q)Let U be a universe.Use an element arguement to prove the following statement.
For all sets A,B and B in P(U),(C-A) u (B-A)⊆ ( B U C) -A.

Def : Z ⊆ W ={(z,w):x∈ X and y ∈ Y}.

Proof:
W=(C-A) U (B-A) ={(c,a):a∈A and c∈C}U{(a,b):a∈A and b∈B}

Z=(B U C)-A = {(a,y):a∈A and y∈BU C}

For all  a∈A:

Case 1.b∈C. If b∈C then (a,b)∈Z. Also (a,b)∈W.

Case 2. b∉C.If b∉C, then b is not in BU C. Then (a,b) is not in Z. b is also not in C-A, so it's not in W.

Case 3. By definition of the Union, a is also a member of C-A and A - C. By definition of intersection, a belongs to(B-A) ∩ (C-A).

Case 4. By definition of a subset, (B-A) ∩ (C-A) is a subset of (B U C) - A.

Case 5. Therefore (B-A) ∩ (C-A)⊆(B U C) - A.

My first time doing element argument.I spend hours to solve this, i want to make sure i am right. Can pls check and advice if i am right or wrong. And where i can make improvemet? Thanks for ur time

Comment: It seems you are using words that you don't seems to understand.  Write "case 1" or "case 2" to denote different scenarios of initial conditions.  It seems you are writing "case 3" and "case 4" to denote different steps in the process without discussing different initial conditions at all.  Furthermore, your definitions you are using for $\subseteq$ don't seem to make sense.  "$Z\subset W = \{(z,w):x\in X, y\in Y\}$".  what does $X$ and $Y$ have to do with anything?

Comment: Also, it was mentioned on a previous one of your questions in the comments as well, please refer to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference on how to type using proper $\LaTeX$ to make formulas easier to read.  (There is no reason to type BUC instead of $B\cup C$, especially since U is being used as the name for the universal set, it should not double as the symbol used for union as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different way to approach element arguments (a.k.a. element chasing): start at the most complex side, expand the definitions, simplify using the laws of logic, and take it from there.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$In this case, let's calculate which $\;x\;$ are in $\;(C - A) \cup (B - A)\;$.

---

For all $\;x\;$,

$$\calc
x \in (C - A) \cup (B - A)
\calcop={definition of $\;\cup\;$}
x \in C - A \;\lor\; x \in B - A
\calcop={definition of $\;-\;$, twice}
(x \in C \land x \not\in A) \;\lor\; (x \in B \land x \not\in A)
\calcop{\tag{*}=}{logic: extract common conjunct $\;x \not\in A\;$}
(x \in C \;\lor\; x \in B) \;\land\; x \not\in A
\calcop={definition of $\;\cup\;$}
(x \in C \cup B) \;\land\; x \not\in A
\calcop={definition of $\;-\;$}
x \in (C \cup B) - A
\endcalc$$

By set extensionality, we've proven $\;(C - A) \cup (B - A) \;=\; (C \cup B) - A\;$.

---

In the above proof, the simplification is done in step $\ref{*}$: that is the key step of this proof.

Note that we've proven equality ($\;=\;$) instead of the weaker $\;\subseteq\;$, since there was no reason to use implication ($\;\Rightarrow\;$) anywhere.

Also, compare this proof to the "elegant set theoretic proof" from [JMoravitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/179297/jmoravitz)'s answer: it has exactly the same structure, but that proof is on the set theory level, and this one is on the element level.

Comment: Thanks but the question asked me to use element argument so i should answer it on element level? If i answer using the elegant set theoretic proof will it be considered wrong though the ans is proven?

Comment: @MohdSaleem The proof in this answer is an element argument.  The proof $$
(C\backslash A)\cup (B\backslash A) = (C\cap A^c)\cup (B\cap A^c) = (C\cup B)\cap A^c = (B\cup C)\backslash A
$$ is not an element argument, but a set theoretic proof, so that would be considered a wrong answer, I think: you've then correctly proven the right thing, but not through the method required by your examiner.

Answer (score 1):

Before anything else, here are some definitions.

> $A\subseteq B$ if and only if for every $a\in A$ you have also that $a\in B$
>
> That is to say, there is nothing that is in $A$ while not in $B$. (note, $\emptyset$ is always a subset of every other set)

Another definition which seems to have confused you

> $A\backslash B = \{x~:~x\in A\text{ and }x\notin B\}$
>
> (equivalently written as $A-B$ or $A\setminus B$ or $A\cap B^c$)

Here is the question as I understand it (given your typing).

Let $U$ be a universe.  Use an element argument to prove the following statement: For all sets $A,B$ and $C$ in $\mathcal{P}(U)$, you have that $(C\backslash A)\cup (B\backslash A)\subseteq (B\cup C)\backslash A$.

Here is an elegant set theoretic proof that uses DeMorgan's laws and symbolic manipulation, (note here that each $=$ can be interpreted left to right as $\subseteq$ while also can be interpreted right to left as $\supseteq$)

$(C\backslash A)\cup (B\backslash A) = (C\cap A^c)\cup (B\cap A^c) = (C\cup B)\cap A^c = (B\cup C)\backslash A$

---

Using an element argument, it should be set up as follows:

$x\in (C\backslash A)\cup (B\backslash A)\Rightarrow x\in (C\backslash A)$ or $x\in (B\backslash A)\Rightarrow (x\in C$ but not $A)$ or $(x\in B$ but not $A)\Rightarrow x\notin A\text{ and }x\in C\cup B$

$\Rightarrow x\in (B\cup C)\cap A^c\Rightarrow x\in (B\cup C)\backslash A\Rightarrow (C\backslash A)\cup (B\backslash A)\subseteq (B\cup C)\backslash A$

If you wish to do a case argument (which is much longer), then consider all possibilities for $x\in^? A, x\in^? B, x\in^? C$ (there are 8 possible configurations) and look to see if each of the eight configurations leads to $x$ being an element of the set on the left and being an element of the set on the right or $x$ not being an element on the left (with no concern about the right).